# Powershell Get-CsOnlineUser is slow to get the Teams user phone number

Tags: powershell, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

I am getting the Teams user Phone numbers using below Powershell commands.

```
# get-numbers.ps1
$PassConv = ConvertTo-SecureString -String "mypass" -AsPlainText -Force
$Cred = New-Object -TypeName "System.Management.Automation.PSCredential" -ArgumentList "user@email.com", $PassConv

Connect-MicrosoftTeams -Credential $Cred -ErrorAction 'Stop'
Get-CsOnlineUser | Select-Object UserPrincipalName,LineUri
```

I am getting the phone numbers using the above commands, but command is very slow.
It takes around 5-10 seconds to connect and get the Phone numbers.

Is there a faster way to get the MS Teams User Phone numbers (LineUri)?

Note:

1. I tested this command on 50+ Mbps internet connection.
2. Using the MS Graph API we can't get the Phone numbers.

Comment: create ticket @ microsoft

Comment: This doesn't look right: `Get-CsOnlineUser Select-Object UserPrincipalName,LineUri` (unless the username you want to query for is actually `Select-Object`)

Comment: There was a typo in the question, the pipe was missing I have updated the question.

Comment: Using Graph we only have [List phones](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/profile-list-phones?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http) to retrieve a list of itemPhone objects from a user's profile. Please note that this is currently under beta and use of these APIs in production applications is not supported.

Comment: The Phone listed in the response is it phone number configured in Teams for the user?

Comment: The response contains phoneType object. It is the type of phone number within the object. Possible values are: home, business, mobile, other, assistant, homeFax, businessFax, otherFax, pager, radio.

Answer (score 0):

Try to import your module in the parent script (if any).

Then for point 2, you're right, outside of businessPhone, I didn't find field containing proper Teams information.

So, here is a suggestion to get faster result but be aware ! That looks like internal microsoft API and may subject to change.

Type F12 when browsing the Teams admin portal and you will see what APIs are called while opening an user.

Once you find the interesting line you can right-click and your browser will generate the code for you (python, powershell, etc.).

Based on that, the following is working in my case (with direct-routing phone numbers):

```
Connect-AzAccount
$token = $(Get-AzAccessToken -ResourceUrl "48ac35b8-9aa8-4d74-927d-1f4a14a0b239").token

$userObjectId = "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx" #get it from usual graph requests
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "https://api.interfaces.records.teams.microsoft.com/Teams.User/users/${userObjectId}?`$select=bvdPhoneNumber" -Headers @{ "authorization"="Bearer $token" } -ContentType "application/json"
```

Notice: to obtains the ID for the resourceUrl I simply took my current token from the stuff extracted through the F12, went into jws.ms and took the audience (aud) value.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but as you mentioned using internal API which is not published may cause temporary solution to the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for guidance. I tested it for various URL destinations over teams admin centrum and it seems fine so far.

Example below for GET call queues

```
$Credential = Get-Credential
Connect-AzAccount -Credential $Credential
$token = $(Get-AzAccessToken -ResourceUrl "https://api.interfaces.records.teams.microsoft.com").token
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "https://api.interfaces.records.teams.microsoft.com/Teams.VoiceApps/callqueues?First=20" -Headers @{ "authorization"="Bearer $token" } -ContentType "application/json"
```

I also tested devicemgmt.teams.microsoft.com for teams devices management automation purposes

```
$token = $(Get-AzAccessToken -ResourceUrl "https://devicemgmt.teams.microsoft.com").token
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33574985)